# Хелп MVC одна точка входа

Tags: php, mvc

Здравствуйте, все не как не могу разобраться в `MVC` с одной точкой входа. Кто изучил именно MVC с одной точкой входа, помогите, покажите входы выходы, мануалы, видео уроки, статьи. Именно те варианты, по которым обучились вы. Прошу не предлагать другие фраемворки.

Comment: Ни по чему не учил, до всего допер сам. И только потом узнал, как это называется. Завтра днем кину простой пример кода.

Comment: Хорошо буду ждать : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сильно упрощенная версия - [тут](http://v3shin.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/siteStruct.zip). Если надо, можно переписать под БД и прикрутить ЧПУ. Это - просто пример, как можно сделать одну точку входа.

Comment: Спасибо что не на блюдочке, сейчас буду совмещать ваши исходники с mvc

Comment: А только один вопрос, Ваша система не хуже чем Точка входа используя .htaccess ?

Answer (score 2):

MVC и одна точка входа это, кагбы, немного разные вещи.(которые просто можно совмещать, что, собственно, делается нередко но вовсе не обязательно для MVC)

По поводу единой точки входа - качаем любой адекватный PHP фреймворк(CodeIgniter, Zend, Kohana и т.д. - на ваш выбор), ковыряем исходники и разбираемся что к чему сами, если не помогло(не получилось или не хотите и пытаться) - гуглим "Фронт контроллер" (это по единой точке входа) и MVC - отдельная тема.

Вообще советую вам почитать книжечку "Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования"( книга, мягко говоря - не идеальна, но это лучшее что я когд-либо находил на данную тематику )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Лично я сначало обучался на известных фреймворках, потом по книгам и по своим простых примерах, ну и потом, ИМХО, лучшее обучение - написать свой "*фреймворк*" (читай **велосипед**)

Но это лучшее что можно придумать в плане обучения... Зато вы потом сможете не просто тупо юзать фреймворк, но и будете понимать "как это чудо устроено", что, для хорошего разработчика немаловажно...

PS: по данному вопросу инфы в интернете навалом

PPS: прочитав какой-то вариант восприятия и понимание того что такое mvc - не спешите этому верить. Да и вообще - важно понять что MVC(ткаим каким он должен быть) - недостежимый идеал(либо нецелесообразно и(или) ущербно достижимый). Тут, в первую очередь - важно понимание идеи.

Comment: я понимаю что MVC и одна точка входа это разные вещи : ) но, я уже пишу для себя сайты на MVC. теперь хочу Mvc + одна точка входа, книги читать не люблю(, буду гуглить Фронт контроллер

Answer (score 1):

[Концепция «единой точки входа»](http://yournet.kz/blog/project/koncepciya-edinoj-tochki-vxoda)